# c++measuring time of program execution

Tags: c++

I have code, in which I can't execute appropriate measuring of the time of functions:
I've used directions from post from hereabout measuring time, and I think everything should be ok, but apparently is not.
Please give me some straight answear, but without links to documentation of c++, because it won't help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;



int ffibr(int n)
{
    if (n<3)
        return 1;

    return ffibr(n-1)+ffibr(n-2);
}
int ffibi(int n)
{
    int a = 1, b = 1,i;
    for (i = 3; i <n+1; i++)
    {
        int c = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }
    return b;
}
int ffibm(int n)
{
    int q11,q12,q21,q22, 
        p11,p12,p21,p22, 
        w11,w12,w21,w22; 

    if(n < 2) return n;



    q11 = q12 = q21 = 1;
    q22 = 0;



    w11 = w22 = 1;
    w12 = w21 = 0;

    n--;     

    while(n)
    {
        if(n & 1)
        {


            p11 = w11*q11 + w12 * q21;
            p12 = w11*q12 + w12 * q22;
            p21 = w21*q11 + w22 * q21;
            p22 = w21*q12 + w22 * q22;



            w11 = p11;
            w12 = p12;
            w21 = p21;
            w22 = p22;

        }

        n >>= 1;    

        if(!n) break;



        p11 = q11*q11 + q12 * q21;
        p12 = q11*q12 + q12 * q22;
        p21 = q21*q11 + q22 * q21;
        p22 = q21*q12 + q22 * q22;



        q11 = p11;
        q12 = p12;
        q21 = p21;
        q22 = p22;

    }

    return w11;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cerr << "Podaj n-ty wyraz ciagu fibonacciego"<<endl;
    cin >> n;


    clock_t poczatek, koniec; 
    double czas1=0;
    poczatek = clock(); 

    for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i)

        return ffibi(n);  

    koniec = clock(); 
    czas1 = (double)(koniec-poczatek)/(double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC); /
system("pause");



    cerr << n<<" wyraz ciagu fibonacciego wyliczony metoda rekurencyjna to " << ffibr(n)<<endl;
    cerr << n<<" wyraz ciagu fibonacciego wyliczony metoda iteracyjna to " << ffibi(n)<<endl;
    cerr << n<<" wyraz ciagu fibonacciego wyliczony metoda macierzy to " << ffibm(n)<<endl;
    cerr << "Czas trwania funkcji ffibi to " << czas1<<endl;
    //cerr << "Czas trwania funkcji ffibr to " << czas2<<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

functions work, but measuring of time don't.I also tried sth like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;



int ffibr(int n)
{
    clock_t poczatek, koniec; // graniczne wartości pomiarowe
    const int ILE = 1000; // liczba powtórzeń mierzonej funkcji
    poczatek = clock(); // początek pomiaru

    for (int i = 0; i<ILE; ++i)
    if (n<3)
        return 1;

    return ffibr(n - 1) + ffibr(n - 2);
    koniec = clock(); // koniec pomiaru
    double czas1 = (koniec - poczatek) / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC*(double)ILE);
}
int ffibi(int n)
{
    int a = 1, b = 1, i;
    for (i = 3; i <n + 1; i++)
    {
        int c = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }
    return b;
}
int ffibm(int n)
{
    int q11, q12, q21, q22, // macierz Q
        p11, p12, p21, p22, // macierz P
        w11, w12, w21, w22; // macierz W

    if (n < 2) return n;

    // ustawiam macierz Q

    q11 = q12 = q21 = 1;
    q22 = 0;

    // w macierzy W tworze macierz jednostkową

    w11 = w22 = 1;
    w12 = w21 = 0;

    n--;      // będzie nam potrzebna n-1 potęga Q

    while (n)
    {
        if (n & 1)
        {
            // wykonujemy mnożenie P = W x Q

            p11 = w11*q11 + w12 * q21;
            p12 = w11*q12 + w12 * q22;
            p21 = w21*q11 + w22 * q21;
            p22 = w21*q12 + w22 * q22;

            // wynik przenosimy: W = P

            w11 = p11;
            w12 = p12;
            w21 = p21;
            w22 = p22;

        }

        n >>= 1;    // usuwamy z n sprawdzony bit

        if (!n) break;

        // podnosimy Q do kwadratu:  P = Q x Q

        p11 = q11*q11 + q12 * q21;
        p12 = q11*q12 + q12 * q22;
        p21 = q21*q11 + q22 * q21;
        p22 = q21*q12 + q22 * q22;

        // wynik przenosimy: Q = p

        q11 = p11;
        q12 = p12;
        q21 = p21;
        q22 = p22;

    }

    return w11;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cerr << "Podaj n-ty wyraz ciagu fibonacciego" << endl;
    cin >> n;


    cerr << n << " wyraz ciagu fibonacciego wyliczony metoda rekurencyjna to " << ffibr(n) << endl;
    cerr << n << " wyraz ciagu fibonacciego wyliczony metoda iteracyjna to " << ffibi(n) << endl;
    cerr << n << " wyraz ciagu fibonacciego wyliczony metoda macierzy to " << ffibm(n) << endl;
    cerr << "Czas trwania funkcji ffibi to " << czas1 << endl;
    //cerr << "Czas trwania funkcji ffibr to " << czas2<<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

I have n idea what is wrong...

Comment: `return ffibi(n);` in your for loop is obviously very wrong.

Comment: `functions work, but measuring of time don't` There are many ways in which something may not work. Please be more specific

Comment: and as i mentioned i did alot of research.

Comment: _"but without links to documentation of c++, because it won't help"_. Why not?

Comment: It does not give the appropriate result.It shows '0'.

Comment: Not solving you immediate problem, but for timing in C++11 (current standard), you can use [chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)

Comment: What system is running the application? Windows provides a system clock with an accuracy around 50 ms if i remember correctly. Some other systems not having a real RTC, but a software driven RTC, often can give wrong results.

Comment: @AD_hypnotizer _"Anyone who want's to help not just comment? "_ BAD attitude.

Answer (score 2):

This will just exit `main()` on the first iteration of the for loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i)

    return ffibi(n);
```

so you won't get a timing result because the rest of `main()` does not even get executed.

Change it to e.g.:

```
for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i)
{
    volatile int result = ffibi(n);  
}
```

Note the use of `volatile` to prevent the compiler from optimising away the redundant loop.

Comment: Why the anonymous down-vote, I wonder ?

Comment: True for the first code segment, but second does not have the return in loop. Probably just a typo.

Comment: @SebastianLange: the second does have a return before the `koniec = clock();` statement in function `int ffibr(int n)`

Comment: My bad. Won't work at all that way.